# Android notification with highest priority

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm trying to create a local notification with the highest priority, which will be displayed no more than 1 time per day. I am trying to do this with:

```
    private fun sendNotification(
        notificationId: Int,
        title: String,
        message: String,
        intent: PendingIntent? = null
    ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) return
        Timber.d("sendNotification")

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this,
            CommonUtils.createNotificationChannelWithSound(this, TAG, SENSOR_SERVICE_CHANNEL, Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
        )

        with(builder) {
            setSmallIcon(
                AppUtils.getNotificationIconId(
                    this@ObserveSensorService,
                    dataManager
                )
            )
            setContentTitle(title)
            setContentText(message)
            color = AppUtils.getNotificationIconColor()
            priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX
            setContentIntent(intent)
        }
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build())
    }

    ----------------------------------

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public static String createNotificationChannelWithSound(Context context, String channelId, String channelName, Uri rawPathUri) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH).build();
        channel.setSound(rawPathUri, att);
        channel.setShowBadge(false);
        NotificationManager service = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        service.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        return channelId;
    }
```

In this case, I receive a notification only in the android blind - even in normal mode with the sound turned on, this notification is not displayed on the lock screen. It does not reproduce any sound or vibration, and even more so I need to receive it in the "silent" and "do not disturb" mode. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes that you might consider applying to your code:

- Change the `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`. To ensure your notification is shown  on the lock screen in normal mode, you should use `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH` (or even `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX` you can).
- Setting visiblity to `Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE` hides notification details from being shown on the lock screen, so if you want full content visible you should do `setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)` or remove that line complely to use defaults.

Aside from the code there's one more thing to check. On my device there's a dedicated option in system settings to control that behavior, so if user say "no notifications on my lock screen" apps won't be able to do anything with it. I'd check that first:

[image: settings]

Comment: I have checked all settings. Notification settings for the application "by default - sound and vibration according to device settings". On the device, the sound is turned on and the "do not disturb" mode is turned off, there is a sound of notifications and vibration from other applications, but not from mine. There is also permission to show notifications on the lock screen. Raising the channel priority did not work

Comment: Hm, for some reason this is not complete answer I see here. I also added a code changes but I do not see it here now. Let me bring that back because you might want to tweak the code too.

Comment: Of course, I will be grateful to you

Comment: Updated my answer. PTAL

Comment: unfortunately, the described code changes did not change the behavior of notifications in any way